# Intermittent Success of using Google Voice Actions "Search in App" Command

Tags: search, google-search, google-voice-actions

I am unable to successfully use the Google System Voice Actions "Search in App" action from the Google App (com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION).

S3: Android v4.3; Google App v5.8.58.16.arm
S6: Android v5.1.1; Google App v5.8.58.19.arm64

Below is what I've tested on both devices on three apps: YouTube, [Recipe App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recipe_app) (this is the sample app used in the [Android tutorial for "Search in App" implementation](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/voice-search)), and an app published onto a Google Play Private Channel (not alpha/beta test):

- Command "Search for '[keyword]' on 'YouTube'": Successful on both
  devices
- Command "Search for '[keyword]' on 'Recipe App'": Never
  successful on S3, worked on S6 before but not now (intermittent
  success). I have not made any changes to settings between then.
- Command "Search for
  '[keyword]' on '[test app restricted to Private Channel]'": Never
  successful on both devices.

(For the test app, I followed the manifest configuration in this tutorial, and using the adb command via Command Prompt:

```
adb shell am start -a "com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" --es query "[query]" -n "[test app]/.MainActivity
```

works perfectly, i.e. the app opens with the correct search query being processed.)

Both devices use the same wifi network which is stable, and all language settings already set to English. I'm quite baffled on why the voice action did not work as intended.

Comment: Are you asking how to get voice commands to recognize the names of any app?

Comment: More specifically, I'm trying to figure out why Google App fails to recognise that "Search [query] in [app]" refers to the Search in App action.